# data.table by with substitute, eval and deparse

Tags: r, data.table

Problem 1: Why it is not consistent?

```
dt <- data.table(x=1:4, y=c(1,1,2,2), z=c(1,2,1,2))

test1 <- function(dt, a){
    t <- deparse(substitute(a))
    dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=t]

}
test1(dt, y) # Works well
   y x
1: 1 3
2: 2 7

test2 <- function(dt, a){
    dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=deparse(substitute(a))]
}
test2(dt, y)
# Error: 'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key().
```

Problem 2:

It seems I can do the following in both frames? Why is that? Which one should I use?

```
test1 <- function(dt, a){
    dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=eval(substitute(a))]

}
test1(dt, y)
   substitute x
1:          1 3
2:          2 7
> 
test2 <- function(dt, a){
    dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=eval(substitute(a), parent.frame())]    
}
test2(dt, y)
   substitute x
1:          1 3
2:          2 7
```

Comment: For (1), I think the error message is pretty clear (you've only pasted the first half of the message). The rest goes like: "Use `by=list(...)` if you can. Otherwise, `by=eval(deparse(substitute(y)))` should work. This is for efficiency so `data.table` can detect which columns are needed". For (2) have a look at `?eval` (as I answered in your other post).

Comment: @Arun Default and explicit arguments are evaluated in different frames https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/227582.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't reproduce the full error:

> test2(dt, y)
>   Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(x = sum(x)), by = deparse(substitute(a))) : 
>     'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(deparse(substitute(a))) should work. This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.

As suggested (or perhaps merely hinted at) you could get success by just enclosing in `c`

```
 test2 <- function(dt, a){
     dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=c(deparse(substitute(a)))]
     }

> test2(dt, y)
   y x
1: 1 3
2: 2 7
```

I think the c() forces an evaluation.

Comment: I thought the success of just using `c(.)` deserved a mention since `eval(deparse(substitute()))` is a wee bit baroque, and I didn't succeed with `list(.)`

Comment: Totally. I was actually referring to `eval(.)` with next sentence. `deparse(substitute(.))` is a relatively rare/unusual case. Objective is to catch common cases. But maybe this could be checked for as well.. Will file a FR just in case, and link back. Thanks again for reviving this post!